# Conflict occurred between username and umbracoUrlAlias

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, short-url

My website developed by Umbraco CMS version 4.11.10.

I used umbracoUrlAlias for creating a shorter URL and my website has capability of user membership.

Unfortunately, There is a problem in it.

When I create a shorter URL for example http://www.mywebsite/**ghasedak** everything is OK.

But if someone creates a username like **ghasedak**, the short URL did not work.
I think they have conflicted.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds strange as the members and the request pipline doesen't have so much to do with eachother.

Is it a clean install? Are you using any custom url rewrites? I just did a clean install, created a content item called "Test" and set the umbracoUrlAlias to "Glenn" wich worked and still works after adding a new member called Glenn.

Are you displaying profiles of the members? Ie. http://www.mywebsite.com/memberName/

Where "memberName" is the name of the member? In that case this is probablt why you are having trubble.

Comment: Thank you.Your answer caused to I check out more and I found the solution.There is a node in my content tree that name's is 'ghasedak'. I deleted it and The problem was fixed.